# PB on Record Change - Field reference in Update Record + Debug Logs

Tags: process-builder

I have created a Process Builder on a custom Object, so I can transfer the values of two fields from the custom Object to the Opportunity.There is a lookup field from the custom Object to the Opportunity that gets populated through trigger.

The process doesn't fire.

```
START
 |
Custom Object (When a record is created or edited)
 |
Update field (No Criteria - just execute the actions) - 
                             Update Records
                                 |
                             Record: [custom_object__c].Opportunities__r 
                                 |
                             Customfield1 on Opp = Field Reference = [custom_object__c].customfield1

                             Customfield2 on Opp = Field Reference = [custom_object__c].customfield2
```

I had a look on communities, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have also tried to troubleshoot the process with Debug Logs, using: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_troubleshoot_debuglogs.htm&type=5, but I am not sure what I am missing. There is no error why it's not firing.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The Process is active and the all 4 fields are text.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Setup debug logs on the Setup-Process Automation: Default workflow user.
Set the debug logs to filter for flow events.
That should help shed some light on the issue.

Confirm the Opp custom field supports the type of information from the custom objects fields. Ensure there is no validation rule prohibiting the info as well

Comment: The Opportunity custom fields support the type of info from the custom object fields. There is no Validation Rule to stop it. I will set the debug logs. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is the Process is active? sometimes it got overlooked can you put the picture of the process if possible

Comment: Hi, The Process is active. I've attached the Debug Logs. Thanks